# No suitable driver found when invoking DriverManager from class constructor

Tags: java, jdbc

Added mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar to the library. Created a class, imported all the java.sql packages. Have public static void main and a constructor. In the `main`, added the line ...

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lookups", "root", "dummyPWd")
```

It does not throw an exception and I can do stuff with the database. Add the same line to the Constructor and I get an error:

> No suitable driver found ...

Why would it work in `main` method but not inside a class constructor?

Comment: did you put your JDBC in your class path?

Comment: I remember before getting a connection that (old) way, you have to register the driver class. Usually this happens with a call to `Class.forName`, and maybe your main does it, while your ctor no

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Also, make sure the library is added in the classpath of your application.

Comment: Your driver JAR file isn't on your CLASSPATH. @Raffaele You're seven years out of date with that statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use a DriverShim class like this one:
http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/dyn-jdbc.html

So you don't need to put the JDBC driver in your classpath.

Works like a charm.

Comment: That just defers the problem. The driver JAR still has to be somewhere. There's no evidence here that he needs runtime driver selection.